# Sql Server Editing Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem in writing query in sql server 2008r2.

**1.** Name column has Words joined e.g.

> Er.Tom, Dr.Katty, Mr.Barney.

How can I separate them in the same column with a ' '(space) i.e

> Er. Tom, Dr. Katty, Mr. Barney.

**2.** Name Column has words joined e.g.

> EngineerPete,EngineerSunny,EngineerRocky

How can I separate them in the same column with a ' '(space) i.e

> Engineer Pete,Engineer Sunny,Engineer Rocky

Thank You in advance

Comment: what will be the basis on how the space will be inserted in between words? i think you need to handle that at the moment records will be inserted.

Comment: Basically I am importing from a flat file source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case, you can do the following:

```
select replace(replace(name, '.', '. '), '.  ', '. ')
```

This replaces a period with a period plus space.  Then it replaces period plus two spaces with period plus a single space -- if you already have a space, then you'll get two spaces in a row.

The second is possibly harder.  For your example:

```
select replace(name, 'Engineer', 'Engineer ')
```

However, that is quite specific to the word "Engineer".

Comment: Thanks that exactly nailed it !!